# Why do I need to do 'using namespace std' instead of 'using std::cout'?

Tags: c++, namespaces

everyone.
I have learnt that it is often desirable to write in my codes using `std::cout` instead of `using namespace std` in order to avoid namespace conflicts. In the following script I only use cout and if I write std:: cout instead of using namespace std; it does not work.
Can anyone please help me understand why? In general, when does `std::cout` not work and I am forced to use `using namespace std`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::cout; //if writing here "using namespace std;" instead, the code does not work

class MyClass{
public:
    string name;
    MyClass (string n)
    {
        name=n;
        cout<<"Hello "<<name;
    }
};


int main()
{
    MyClass MyObj("Mike");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"I only use cout"* - There's a line there that uses `string` too. Declaring `std::cout` isn't going to make the string line work. I mean, you know it brings only *one* name in. So it should not be a surprise that another name you didn't bring in isn't working.

Comment: Just use `std::cout` and `std::string`. It really isn't that much to ask for... Have some self-respect. ;)

Comment: Thanks, everyone! I just started learning C++ two weeks ago, so please expect my questions to be  really simple :)

Comment: when asking questions please post the code that doesn't work rather than the code that does

Comment: @AlanBirtles. Understood. I will update the question right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works okay with:

```
using std::cout;
```

statement for `cout`, but the compiler must know the location of `string` (actually it's `std::string`) too which you're currently using. You must define:

```
using std::string;
```

---

When you enter:

```
using namespace std;
```

It calls the entire namespace called `std` which contains a variety of features added as C++ standard library and then you don't need to use prefix `std::` for those functions/classes/variables of that namespace.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `using std::string;` along with `using std::cout;` to make it work as you're *not only using cout from namespace std*, `string` is also a member of `namespace std` which you are using in your code.